# How to remove brackets when using property transfer?

Tags: soapui, jsonpath

I'm a beginner on soapUI. Since yesterday, I'm working on transferring property from a response to a parameter of another API.

I'm trying this with an API of OpenStreetMap that converts address into coordinates. But when transferring that property, it keeps the brackets that leads to a 404 error on my other API.

For example, for the Eiffel Tower address, the beginning of the answer of OSM API is :

```
[
    {
        "place_id": "64537015",
        "licence": "Data © OpenStreetMap contributors, ODbL 1.0. https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright",
        "osm_type": "way",
        "osm_id": "5013364",
        "boundingbox": [
            "48.8574753",
            "48.8590465",
            "2.2933084",
            "2.2956897"
        ],
        "lat": "48.8582602",
        "lon": "2.29449905431968",
        "display_name": "Tour Eiffel, 5, Avenue Anatole France, Gros-Caillou, 7e, Paris, Île-de-France, France métropolitaine, 75007, France",
        //etc
    }
]
```

My code for the transferring property value is :

```
$..boundingbox[1,2]
```

And here are the transferred values :

```
[[48.8590465, 2.2933084]]
```

I'd like it without brackets...

Comment: Show you code / script from Soap UI.

Answer (score 3):

In the property transfer, you're getting the raw response from the JSONPath processor, brackets and all, so you'd need to do some pre- or post-processing of the values.

One option is to post-process the transferred value using a Groovy test step. Assuming your property transfer is going to a test-suite level property called `latlong`:

```
// Assuming the transferred-to property is at the test suite level
def testSuiteProperty = testRunner.testCase.testSuite.getPropertyValue( "latlong" )
log.info testSuiteProperty

def strippedProperty = testSuiteProperty.replaceAll("\\[", "").replaceAll("\\]","");
log.info strippedProperty
```

This produces:

```
48.8574753, 2.2933084
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I tried your solution and here is the answer of Soap UI : "java.lang.nullPointerException: Cannot invoke method replaceAll() on null object. Error at line 5"

Comment: I don't know how you've set up your soapUI project, so to demonstrate the code I've made an assumption you have a test-suite level custom property (the code comment points to this). You'll need to define `testSuiteProperty ` according to what you have set up.